# how to convert markdown files to html with find command

Tags: bash, find

I have some files on my project having extensions as `.md.`
I want to convert all those files to `.html` through the **find** command.
The command I use to convert a `markdown` file to `html` is:
`md2html file.md > file.html` 
How can I do it?
And if I want to save the HTML files in different directory?

Comment: Use`find` command to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find/read` command combination to do this:

```
find /your/path/to/mdfiles -type f -name "*.md" -printf "%f\0"\
| while read -rd '' filename
do
   md2html "${filename}" "/your/html/dir/${filename%.md}.html"
done
```

should do it.

---

**Explained**

- `find /your/path/to/mdfiles -type f -name "*.md"` finds all the files that have the extention  `.md`.
- We parse the result strings/filenames using `while-read -rd ''`
- `${filename%.md}` trims the `.md` at the end of each filename
- So `${filename%.md}.html` trims the `.md` and adds `.html`
- `md2html ${filename} "${filename%.md}.html"` does the job for each file which passed by the find command.
- `-printf "%f\0"` gives you the null-terminated file basenames, which is useful if you wish to copy the files to different directory.

---

**Slightly shorter vresion**

```
find . -type f -name "*.md" -printf "%f\0" -exec bash -c 'md2html "$1" "/your/html/dir/${1%.md}.html"' _ {} \;
```

Replace `/your/html/dir/` with `your path`

Comment: It's only printing, not creating files of html

Comment: @Albert Sorry there was a redundant `-print0` in the script which I have just removed. Please try both versions and lemme know the result

Comment: One more question, If I want to take only the file name without the whole path, what I need to add?

Comment: `-printf "%f"` option with `find` gives you the filename without the whole path

Comment: So how it should be, the whole statement

Comment: @Albert : Sorry what you've asked is not immensely clear to me . For instance, what do you mean by `take only the file name without the whole path`?

Comment: `find /your/path/to/mdfiles -type f -name "*.md"` returns the whole path, I need only the name of the file

Comment: `find /your/path/to/mdfiles -type f -name "*.md" -printf "%f"` returns only the filenames

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

You could do it something like:

```
find path -type f -name "*.md" -exec sh -c 'md2html "${0}" > "${0%md}.html"' {} \;
```

- Path you would need to give directory where you wish to search for md files.
- type says you want to search for file and not directories.
- name says you wish to search for all file with md extension.
- exec would execute the command on files that were found.

Comment: You can modify this slightly to get an output file of `foo.html` instead of `foo.md.html`: `-exec sh -c 'md2html "$0" "${0%md}html"' {} \;`. This will also avoid any problems if a found file has whitespace or other characters that need to be quoted in its file name.